# Append element in IE7

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7

I append a select-element to a DOM-Node and fill it dynamically, which works good in Firefox and Safari. Unfortunately, when I click on the select-box, it simple does not drop down in Internet Explorer. Any ideas what goes wrong here?

```
    $('<select size="1">').appendTo(
            $('#mytable tbody')
            .find('tr:last')
            .find('th.col1')
            )
            .attr('id', 'select_' + counter)
            .append('<option>New Option</option>')
            .click(function() {

                var t = $(this);

                    // Get matching alternatives as json
                    $.getJSON(Drupal.settings.basePath + 'mymodule/product_cat/' + data['product_category'], function(cat_data) {
                        t.find('option').remove();
                        $.each(cat_data, function(i,item){
                            t.append($("<option value='" + JSON.stringify(item) + "'>" + item.name + "</option>"));
                        });
                        t.find('option:first').attr('selected', 'selected');
                    });

            })
            .change(function() {
                tmparr = $(this).attr('id').split('_');
                set_row_data($(this).parent().parent(), $(this).val());
            });
}
```

**-- UPDATE --**

I inspected the code that the selectbox contains in IE7 after updating - the options it got via json seeem to be inserted in the dom-tree correctly, so it looks like the issue is somewhere else. Any ideas appreciated.

**-- UPDATE 2 --**

The Problem of IE7 seems to be in the .click()-function:

If I place some code like this:

```
$('#myelement').append('<option>foo</option>');
```

it works fine even in IE7.

If i place it into a click-function like this:

```
$('#myelement').click(function() {
  $(this).append('<option>foo</option>');
});
```

the problem appears.

**-- SOLUTION --**

What nobody noticed (above all: me), was, that my first line is buggy:

```
$('<select size="1">').appendTo(...
```

should be

```
$('<select size="1"></select>').appendTo(...
```

Works now, thanks anyway everybody.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see solution update

Answer (score 0):

**Disable caching in your json**. There is many programmers facing this problem such as [this one](http://greenash.net.au/posts/thoughts/an-ie-ajax-gotcha-page-caching).

**EDIT**

from [codecouch](http://www.codecouch.com/2009/01/how-to-stop-internet-explorer-from-caching-ajax-requests/):

> A workaround is to use a ‘cache buster’ parameter in your GET request. Something like this:

```
var urlToFetch = 'whatever?randNum=' + new Date().getTime();
```

> This works very well, but can have drawbacks, depending on your server setup. For example, if your application server sits behind a caching layer, you wouldn’t want the URL to be different every time for idempotent requests, as the cached version would never get used, and so your application server would get a direct hit every time.

Comment: could you elaborate this a bit more, please?

Comment: thanks for your suggestion - I implemented both now (suggested headers and url modification), but it does not solve the problem. The content of the selectbox seems to "slip down a few pixels" and does not drop down on click any more.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `'<select size="1" id="select_' + counter + '">'` is a valid selector...

try it with `'#select_'+counter`

Comment: this selector is valid. To be sure, i changed the code to $('<select size="1">').appendTo(..).attr('id', '...'), but it does not work, either.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it makes any difference but try changing:

```
$('<select size="1">').appendTo($('#mytable tbody')
            .find('tr:last')
            .find('th.col1')).attr('id', 'select_' + counter)
```

to

```
$('#mytable tbody').find('tr:last').find('th.col1')
                   .append($('<select size="1">')
                   .attr('id', 'select_' + counter);

$('#select_' + counter).append.....
```

..fredrik

Comment: What does IE7 say if you run the debugger about $(this).get(0).nodeName ? (inside you click method)